# Text retrieval from an image is not appropriate

Tags: r, image-processing, tesseract, rmagick, text-recognition

I have an image where it contains names of several resources. 
When I am trying to read the text from  the image using R its not throwing how it is present in image. 
For instance J is reported as I Or JI, 
Xyz1 is reported as XyzL 
I used tesseract and magick packages but still I am facing the issue.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What you are encountering is probably part of the imprecision with some image to text conversion. This question might be better asked on stats.stackexchange as it relates to the use of machine learning techniques not programming.

Comment: i posted in the above mentioned link as well..thanks.-@Simon.S.A.

Comment: Please anyone provide a solution to fix the above issue